# Received error while encrypting and decrypting using aes-256-cbc algorithm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I tried this using the following JavaScript code to encrypt the string:
my text is 'icicihdfcaxizsbi'

```node
const encrypt = (text) => {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, Buffer.from(key), iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
    return {
        iv: iv.toString('binary'),
        encryptedData: encrypted.toString('binary'),
        key: key.toString('binary')
    };
}
```

I tried this using the following JavaScript code to decrypt the string:

```node
const decrypt = (text) => {
    let iv = Buffer.from(text.iv, 'binary');
    let enKey = Buffer.from(text.key, 'binary');
    let encryptedText = Buffer.from(text.encryptedData, 'binary');
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(enKey), iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
    return decrypted.toString();
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: code formatting